# Return generic value from switch expression in Java-12

Tags: java, generics, switch-statement, java-12, switch-expression

I am wondering if there is an option to return a generic type from a Java 12 switch expression.

The basic code can look like that:

```
boolean result = switch(ternaryBool) {
    case TRUE -> true;
    case FALSE -> false;
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Seriously?!");
};
```

Is there anything against doing it this way?

```
T result = switch(ternaryBool) {
    case TRUE -> BooleanUtils.toBoolean('true');
    case FALSE -> new Integer(0);
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Seriously?!");
};
```

EDIT:

Maybe better example from my case: I need to have few classes which are representing primitive & complex data structures. I have also factory method which is creating this `DataPointValue` based on an enum from other system and unknown value (**let's forget about casting exceptions**):

```
public static <T> IDataPointValue create(T value, DATA_TYPE dataType) throws Exception {
    try {
        switch (dataType) {
            case BOOL:
                return new BoolDataPointValue((Boolean) value);
            case INT:
                return new IntDataPointValue((Integer) value);
            case WORD:
                return new IntDataPointValue((Integer) value);
            case STRING:
                return new StringDataPointValue((String) value);
            case REAL:
            case FLOAT:
                return new RealDataPointValue((Float) value);
            case DINT:
                return new DIntDataPointValue((Integer) value);
            case DWORD:
                return new DWordDataPointValue((Integer) value);
            default:
                throw new Exception("Data Type not implemented: " + dataType);
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new Exception("Could not create DPV in terms of Type incompability");
    }
}
```

Is there any profit to move this code and use switch expression from Java 12?

Comment: That's not really a generic type is it? Wouldn't a generic type require them all to return the same type, just the uniform type they return could change? You could just have it return `Object`, and sort it out after.

Comment: Yeah, that was just for simplification. I was thinking about something more complex of course.

Comment: Perhaps you should post an example that better represents the situation you are asking about.

Comment: Returning `Object` is not recommended. You should build your own hierarchy and encapsulate all the values in those classes. Once that is done , you can subtitute a subclass with super-class. That way you can also use `Dynamic binding`(no need for `instanceof` operator.

Comment: @KhanSaab Yes, `Object` was a bad suggestion, but it made slightly more sense than using generics.

Comment: Or perhaps use `var`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I added example from my code :)

Comment: If one of the answers answered your question please mark it as a accepted. If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything against doing it this way?

[JEP 325: Switch Expressions (Preview)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325)  in one of the columns states the following about the extended representation of the switch statement(formatting mine):

> A switch expression is a *poly expression*; **if the target type is
> known, this type is pushed down into each arm**.
>
> The type of a switch expression is its target type if known; **if not, a standalone type is computed by combining the types of each case arm.**

Holding the above as true, the type of the switch expression as you wrote it, could possibly be an `Object` unless you've specifically formed a custom model and encapsulated the types.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any profit to move this code and use switch expression from java12?

This really depends on what you count as profit. There are a couple of things that immediately come to mind when looking at the corresponding `switch` expression:

```
public static <T> IDataPointValue create(T value, DATA_TYPE dataType) {
    return switch (dataType) {
        case BOOL ->        new BoolDataPointValue((Boolean) value);
        case INT ->         new IntDataPointValue((Integer) value);
        case REAL, FLOAT -> new RealDataPointValue((Float) value);
        // ...
    };
}
```

1. You don't need a `default` case since the compiler knows you are dealing with all of the enum values (run-time changes to the enum will cause problems).
2. It's a bit more readable since you `return` on the whole expression and not in each `case` explicitly, and since you don't need to deal with fallthrough semantics.

---

As for the generics side of the question, it's not that clear. For one, your method is declaring a genetic parameter without bounds and using it only once, so there is no real point in it. The declaration

```
public static <T> IDataPointValue create(T value, DATA_TYPE dataType)
```

is the same as

```
public static IDataPointValue create(Object value, DATA_TYPE dataType)
```

because `T` doesn't add any info. You might want to ask a new question about your data structures.